# How MVC Update Model works with incomplete objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view that is bound to an object called "Requisition"
On this view we are only modifying is child records.

My question is: **When I submit the form I have the object requisitionForm, and this object is only partially complete.**

How do I save just the new changes?

Should I take the requisitionForm (incomplete) and merge it with requisition (complete) ?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `requisitionForm` parameter, and call `UpdateModel(requisition)`

Comment: max - thanks
I tried that and got this error: The model of type 'MS.Domain.Entities.Requisition' could not be updated

Comment: @aron: You can call `TryUpdateModel(requisition)`, if it returns false you'll get the errors in `ModelState`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/